# Best way to make multi-client udp server on single port

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, udp

I have ready tcp multi-thread support.
I creating one thread per each tcp connection.
Now I'm trying to add udp support.
In comparison to tcp, udp is connectionless.
I see only three ways to handle it.
1.Each udp client on different ports.(looking for another way)
2.Get ip address of udp packet then itterate through tcp connection list...(this way is crappy because I will be able to handle only one client per one IP. I know a lot of peoples have internal ip = one ip a lot of players).
3.Each tcp client have also unique id(int).I generate id on connection to server.I can try to just send those id on beggining of udp packet. 
(this way seems to be good but what with cheaters ?If they just edit packet and resend with random different id this will cause like playerX is on posX 50 and posY 50. And will open way to hacks another players.
Any different ideas ? :) 
Which will be the best way to identification who is who?
I need it for my game as tcp at some point causing too much lags...

Comment: For point 3 regarding cheaters. You can create an id that has nothing to do with the players in the game. E.g. you have 10 Players connected to the server and each registers via tcp and generates a unique id using `long`. Pretty unlikely a cheater guesses the right id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use multiple ports, there's no point in doing that. And if you're afraid of "cheaters", well, they might as well just try connecting to a different port, so you're back in square one.
2. IP addresses and source port numbers are usually unique per connection. NAT devices (home routers that have internal IPs) generally assign different external ports to different connections. So a combination of source IP + source port *should* be unique, and should work in most cases. Now about the edge cases... Since source IPs and ports can be easily forged in UDP, you'd still need your own mechanism for authenticating user traffic. What I suggest is using IDs like you suggested in your third point. Only use random, per-connection IDs. If you use some large random value for each connection (say a [128 bit UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)), there's no chance anyone could fake it. In fact, you'll probably be fine with a much smaller random number, say 32 bits (like TCP).